# Matrix with the same value in all entries — which notation to use?

Tags: matrices, notation

Pretty trivial but for a matrix

\begin{bmatrix}x&x&\ldots&x&x\\x&x&\ldots&x&x\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&x&x\\x&x&\ldots&x&x\end{bmatrix}

with  $N\times N $, is there is simpler notation. I had $A=[x_{i,j}]\in \Bbb R^{N\times N}$ in my mind, but I can't find anywhere were it is used

Edit: I forgot to mention but, I need to work with the elements in the matrix, so like doing scalar multiplication (to do a proof by the principle of mathematical induction question). But it a $3\times 3$ so I figured out I do have to write every single element 9 times in a row. Is there any notation that can make my math simpler?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming that $x \neq 0$, it's a rank-$1$ matrix. Thus, to emphasize its rank-$1$-ness, I would use

$$\color{blue}{x \,{\Bbb 1}_n {\Bbb 1}_n^\top}$$

Comment: I am actually new to matrices, what do you mean by rank-1? Does it mean that the no row is depended on any other row?

Comment: @AdilMohammed By rank-$1$, I mean that all columns are scaled versions of the exact same column vector. If you take a linear combination of the columns, you always end up on the same line passing through the origin, a $1$-dimensional vector space.

Comment: Also just a clarification, \color{blue}{2 \,{\Bbb 1}_n {\Bbb 1}_n^\top}  is the notation for \begin{bmatrix}2&2&\ldots&2&2\\2&2&\ldots&2&2\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&2&2\\2&2&2\end{bmatrix} and the first n tells us the number of column and second the row?

Comment: @AdilMohammed An $m \times n$ matrix of ones could be written as ${\Bbb 1}_m {\Bbb 1}_n^\top$.

Comment: thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @AdilMohammed If you wanted a matrix whose 1st column is $m$ ones, whose 2nd column is $m$ twos, etc, you could write ${\Bbb 1}_m {\rm r}^\top$, where $ {\rm r} = (1,2,\dots,n)$.

Answer (score 8):

It is common for $J$ or $J_{n}$ to be used as a square ($n \times n$) matrix of all 1s, though not so common that you shouldn't specify that this is what you mean. You can also write $J_{m,n}$ for an $m \times n$ matrix of all ones.  It is also common for ${\bf{j}}$ to be used for a vector of all ones.

These all ones matrices and vectors come up in a variety of situations in algebra and combinatorics; for example

1. $J_{n}-I_{n}$ is the adjacency matrix for the complete graph $K_{n}$
2. $J_{m,n}$ is the identity element for the set of $m\times n$ matrices under the Hadamard product;
3. the proof of Fisher's Inequality for combinatorial designs relies on the fact that the incidence matrix of such a structure must satisfy the equation $B^{T}B=(r-\lambda)I+\lambda J$ (where $r$ and $\lambda$ are parameters of the design).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a common notation, as this type of matrix isn't extremely common. However in Statistics I have seen a column or matrix of ones written as a $J$.